# asp.net web.config test vs production

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm working on asp.net c# web application. And now I'm facing an issue with web services.

I copied the source code from production and put into my virtual machine for testing and development. However, some of the web services are not being changed while changing the URL from web.config.

I got lost trying to figure out why this happens.

Is there a place where it might be changing this web service reference to a static web service location? i.e to production always. Because currently, I'm supposed to have all the links to the testbed. Even though all of my web services inside web.config are referring to testbed, but this was keeps pointing to prod.

Please your advice.

Comment: Briefly that comes into my mind that might help is 1) After changing the web.config, have you restart the iis etc? 2) Is there any caching currently in place (ie: you read from the cache - rather than hitting the testbed web services).

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, how can i restart iis if i'm running the app on visual studio 2010 on my local machine?

Comment: You could open command prompt under Administrator mode - type in "iisreset" and press enter (presumably within your virtual machine)